# Using booleans in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to replace string values in an array with the array median, but I am getting an error code when I try to make a boolean. I have a defined array with 3 string values and the code I am trying to enter is:

```
arr2 = np.array ([1,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,2,
                  4,1,3,4,1,2,5,3,2,
                  1,"?",1,"n",3,2,5,
                  1,2,"Nan",3,2,2,4,3])

flag_good = [element.isdigit() for element in arr2]
flag_bad = ~flag_good
```

but I get an error code when running the line:

```
flag_bad = ~flag_good
```

How would I go about replacing the sting values with the array's median?

Comment: I apologize for the formatting it did retain its original format

Comment: Edit the question to show the full error message as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde operation is part of numpy and is a shortcut for [numpy.invert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html).

By using a list comprehension, `flag_good` is a Python list, which doesn't support this operation.

For example, you can convert the list `flag_good` to a Numpy array and then use the invert function.

```py
>>> flag_bad = ~np.array(flag_good)
>>> flag_bad
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Or you can use [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) and directly return a Numpy array where the function is called elementwise instead of using the list comprehension.

```py
>>> flag_good = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.isdigit())(arr2)
>>> flag_bad = ~flag_good
>>> flag_bad
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Comment: Thank you. The Boolean is now working like you have showed. But It is reporting an error when I try and run the code:   arr2[FlagBad] = np.median(arr2[FlagGood]) is the function different on an array contains string  and digit values then an array containing only digit values? I am trying to replicate a function I wrote to replace outliers with a mean, but this is replacing string values with a median and it is proving to be much different

Comment: @GregSullivan Which code exactly doesn't work? And what's the error message?

Comment: File "/Users/gregorysullivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3561, in _median
    return mean(part[indexer], axis=axis, out=out)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in mean
  File "/Users/gregorysullivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3257, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gregorysullivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 151, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: @GregSullivan And which code do you execute? In the code listed above their is no mean function or something like that.

Comment: The code I executed was:    arr2[FlagBad2] = np.median(arr2[FlagGood2]) but after seeing the error code and working on it I entered:    arr2[FlagBad2] = np.median(arr2[FlagGood2].astype(int)) and it worked! Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you could solve the problem from the beginning, editing your list comprehension.

`flag_bad = [not(element.isdigit()) for element in arr2]`

To answer your question, though, I'd do this:

```
import numpy as np
input_list = [1,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,2,
                  4,1,3,4,1,2,5,3,2,
                  1,"?",1,"n",3,2,5,
                  1,2,"Nan",3,2,2,4,3]

# calculate the median
median = int(np.median([elt for elt in input_list if type(elt) is int])) 

# replace elements of the list only if you have a non-int 
output_array = np.array([elt if type(elt) is int else median for elt in input_list])
print(output_array)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 1 5 2 3 4 2 4 1 3 4 1 2 5 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 2 5 1 2 2 3 2 2 4 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't think python will calculate the median when there is string and int values in the array, and that is what I was struggling to figure out.

Comment: @GregSullivan Yes. That's why I only use the integers from the list to calculate the median. The code above should work on any platform without any errors.